# Why google styleguide suggests to use optional int64_t by default for big integers?

Tags: c++, c++11

Google [styleguide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Integer_Types) suggests to use `int64_t` when value is "greater than or equal to 2^31", but according to [standard](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/) it is optional, so wouldn't it be better to use `int_least64_t`? What benefits of use int64_t besides shorter name?

Comment: There aren't any C++11 platforms without `int64_t`, and probably there will never be

Comment: @M.M Why then standard mentions it as an optional?

Comment: The standard usually errs on the side of caution, when it comes to platform support

Answer (score 2):

`int64_t` has a known size, `int_least64_t` might be larger than 64-bits. Dealing with a data type with a known size is much easier than one that might be bigger and introduce subtle bugs on platforms where `int_least64_t` is not 64-bits.

I'm not aware of a platform that google is likely to be targetting that doesn't support 64-bit integers.

Comment: Is there any platforms at all, which has a C++11 compiler, and don't support `int64_t`?

Comment: @geza I wouldn't be surprised if there is, something like an embedded system that only supports 32-bit maths.

Comment: I've just asked about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51590607/are-there-any-platforms-where-fixed-width-types-intxx-t-are-missing. Note, however, the compiler has to give an at-least-64-bit types, because `long long` has to be at least 64-bit.